# Underdetermined regression coefficient bootstrap hypothesis test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, regression-coefficients, bootstrap

Unlike the method of performing hypothesis testing in general, we tried to obtain a kind of z score by dividing the mean of the regression coefficients obtained through bootstrap by the standard deviation of the distribution of each regression coefficient, and infer statistical significance through z scoring. ($H_0: b = 0$)
My guess is that these transformations are nearly z-score-like, so setting a threshold of $z > 1.96$ or $z < -1.96$ could lead to hypothesis testing with $p < 0.05$.
So I did the following simulation.

1. $X$ is a 30x1000 matrix where all variables follow $N(0,1)$. (in matlab, `X = normrnd(0,1,30,1000)`)
2. $y$ is generated by multiplying some columns (I used 5 variables in columns 1, 3, 5, 7, 9) by the appropriate coefficients. In my case the coefficients were 3, 2, -5, 1, 4.
3. Case resampling 30 samples were randomly re-sampled through bootstrap, and ridge regression was performed on the obtained samples.
4. After a total of 5000 iterations, the average of the regression coefficients corresponding to each variable was divided by the standard deviation of the regression coefficients and converted into a kind of z score. The regularization parameter were set the same in every iteration.
5. Hypothesis tests were performed on 995 unrelated variables through the z score threshold. I thought I would get a false positive rate of about 5%.

However, setting a threshold of $z > 1.96$ or $z < -1.96$ yielded about 11% false positives, far more than 5%.

Is it a matter of not proceeding with the comparison with the null distribution? Why can't I test for statistical significance with this method?